# How to broadcast or send messages to multiple user from page using facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

I am using the facebook webhook, i am sending the messages to the messaged user using this format

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "recipient": {
    "id": "USER_ID"
  },
  "message": {
    "text": "hello, world!"
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/messages?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"`

as mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference). Now i am storing all the messages in database and want to send the message at once to all the messaged user, as i have seen in [chatfuel](http://chatfuel.com/) there is a broadcast option. is there a option like broadcast from facebook api please help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: No, there is not. You have to send the message to each user individually.

Comment: Thank you for replying, then how chatfuel is using broadcast option?

Comment: Most likely: By sending the message to each user individually …